# custom background image with large titles NavigationBar in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios11

How do you set a custom background image for the large title NavigationBar in iOS 11? I'm using a custom subclass which I've assigned to the navigationControllers in the storyboard.

This is how I create my custom NavBar:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:0.6)
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
            self.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
            self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
        }
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "navigationBarBackground"), for: .default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "navigationBarShadow")
    }
}
```

Strangely the `setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)` doesn't work for the large titles. It worked before with iOS 10 and also if I rotate the iPhone (and activate the small NavBar) the background is back?

**Edit:**
The `backgroundImage` is still rendered but somehow hidden. Only if you start scrolling and the "normal" Navigation Bar appears, the backgroundImage is visible. Also the `barTintColor` is completely ignored in this case.
[image: screenshot]
[image: GIF]

Comment: hi @alexkaessner. did you find any solution of the problem..?

Comment: @OceanBlue No! :/ I‘ve just inspected the new NavBar a bit. Seems like there‘s a completely different view for the big layout shown, but this view doesn’t change.

Comment: it is possible to set navigationbar background color or bartintcolor. but unfortunately i can't set the navigationbar background image. Is this a bug of ios 11 ?  do you know anything..?

Comment: @OceanBlue I've just added some more analyze info, but it seems like a bug. I will file a report to Apple later!

Comment: Any news about this bug?

Comment: @Tulleb Not at all. Apple marked it as "duplicate of 33345493", but the issue is still open.

Comment: Did anyone find a workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Finally I found solution!**

Edit: Works on iOS 13 and higher

---

You can use it before view appears, eg: in viewDidLoad() method:

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let largeTitleAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance() 

        largeTitleAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        largeTitleAppearance.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "BackgroundImage.png")

        self.navigationBar.standardAppearance = largeTitleAppearance
        self.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = largeTitleAppearance
    }
```

---

All that you need is:

1. Create UINavigationBarAppearance instance:

   ```
   let largeTitleAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
   ```

   Apple documentation:

   > **UINavigationBarAppearance** - An object for customizing the appearance of a navigation bar.

---

2. Configure it:

   ```
   largeTitleAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
   ```

   "Opaque" here because we want to set colorised image (but in practice it doesn't matter, what configure will you set)

---

3. Set background image:

   ```
   largeTitleAppearance.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "BackgroundImage.png") // Set here image that you need
   ```

---

4. Assign our *largeTitleAppearance* object to both *standardAppearance* and *scrollEdgeAppearance* navigationBar's fields:

   ```
   self.navigationBar.standardAppearance = largeTitleAppearance // For large-navigationBar condition when it is collapsed
   self.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = largeTitleAppearance // For large-navigationBar condition when it is expanded
   ```

   Apple documentation:

   > **.standardAppearance** - The appearance settings for a standard-height navigation bar.
   >
   > **.scrollEdgeAppearance** - The appearance settings to use when the edge of any scrollable content reaches the matching edge of the navigation bar.

---

This helped to me: https://sarunw.com/posts/uinavigationbar-changes-in-ios13/#going-back-to-old-style

Comment: This is the correction solution in iOS 13. The UIColor(patternImage:) solutions are just hacks.

Comment: Awesome, that's the proper solution! Thanks for sharing it to this old post. Crazy that it took Apple soo long to introduce this.

Comment: Btw, if you need to change the background image stretching/positioning take a look at [`backgroundImageContentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarappearance/3197996-backgroundimagecontentmode)

Comment: Works with SwiftUI too!

Comment: @HarryJ Ohhh, this is what I need. Do you need to use a UIHostingController or is there another way?

Comment: @Jeremy chuck this within the `init()` function of the View and you should be sweet

Comment: @HarryJ I tried that but don't have access to the `self.navigationBar` in `init()`. (You can access the `UINavigationBar.appearance()` but I don't want to set it globally). I was then using this approach (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427754/155186) to set it individually, but ran into the problem where the customization doesn't work for the initial SceneDelegate. :(

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue, fixed it by

Remove setBackgroundImage and use barTint color with pattern image

```
let bgimage = imageWithGradient(startColor: UIColor.red, endColor: UIColor.yellow, size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 1))
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: bgimage!)
```

Get image with gradient colors

```
func imageWithGradient(startColor:UIColor, endColor:UIColor, size:CGSize, horizontally:Bool = true) -> UIImage? {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    if horizontally {
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    } else {
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
    gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Comment: I’ve tried this as well, but I want the image to be stretched and not tiled. My image has a gradient…or is there a way to change those properties for `patternImage:`?

Comment: Okay I've tested this now and the problem is still the tiling. If I rotate the iPhone the gradient is too short and repeats. Also the ´horizontally: false´ isn't working correctly. It's just a orange bar background.

Comment: Life savier :-)

Comment: What if we want to have our own background image with no pattern or gradient color. just a simple image i want to show it as is.  Do you have any idea what should be the size of the navigation bar background image?

Comment: This works perfectly for both a regular title size and a large title size, Thank you.

Comment: Works perfectly, but should be noted that this code goes inside a custom NavigationController, not a ViewController.

Answer (score 6):

In iOS 11 you no more need set BackgroundImage(Remove its declaration) if you use large titles. Instead you need use BarTintColor.

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:0.6)
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
            self.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
            self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:1)
        }
        else {
            self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "navigationBarBackground"), for: .default)                
        }
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "navigationBarShadow")
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, but this isn't a real solution. I've also tested and analyzed a little more and seems like I have to stick to the traditional Navigation Bar (for now).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Do you have any idea what should be the size of the navigation bar background image (navigationBarBackground in your example)?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code (Swift 4.0):

in viewDidLoad()

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
} else {
    //iOS <11.0
}
self.title = "Title"
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "nav_bg"))
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on oldrinmendez's answer - that solution works perfect for a horizontal gradient.

For a VERTICAL gradient, I was able to use the same function from oldrinmendez's answer by calling it again in scrollViewDidScroll. This continually adjusts the height of the gradient image as the user scrolls.

**Start with the function from oldrinmendez :**

```
func imageWithGradient(startColor:UIColor, endColor:UIColor, size:CGSize, horizontally:Bool) -> UIImage? {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
        if horizontally {
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        } else {
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
```

**Create an update function to call it with the options you want:**

```
func updateImageWithGradient() {

        let navBarHeight  = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height
        let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        let heightAdjustment: CGFloat = 2

        let gradientHeight = navBarHeight! + statusBarHeight + heightAdjustment

        let bgimage = imageWithGradient(startColor: UIColor.red, endColor: UIColor.orange, size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: gradientHeight), horizontally: false)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: bgimage!)
    }
```

**Finally add the update function to scrollViewDidScroll & ViewDidApper:** Use ViewDidAppear so the correct navigation bar height is returned

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        updateImageWithGradient()
    }

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
        updateImageWithGradient()
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin it would be like this:

```
this.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

      var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer
      {
        Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Width,
              UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Height + this.NavigationBar.Frame.Height),
        Colors = new CGColor[]
              {Constants.Defaults.Navigation.RealBlueColor.ToCGColor(), Constants.Defaults.Navigation.RealBlueColor.ToCGColor()}
      };

      UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(gradientLayer.Bounds.Size);
      gradientLayer.RenderInContext((UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext()));
      UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

      this.View.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
      this.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(image);
```

The *this.View.Layer.Insert* is optional. I need it when I'm "curling" up and down an image on the NavigationBar

Answer (score 0):

Changing the barTint didn't work for me so I change the layer inside navigationBar

```
 navigationBar.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:
        UIImage(named: "BG-Roof1")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets:
            UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0), resizingMode: .stretch)).cgColor
```

Comment: Nope, same here for iOS 12