# UINavigationBar background Image - broken in iOS 11?

Tags: uinavigationbar, background-image, ios11, xcode9

The following code *was* working **perfectly fine** for setting a custom image as the background of a UINavigationBar:

```
    // In AppDelegate.swift: 
    let image = UIImage(named:"HeaderBanner-new")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.defaultPrompt)
```

Since switching to Xcode 9, Swift 4, and iOS 11, this code no longer works. All I'm getting is a plain white background in the UINavigationBar.

I also tried moving the code out of the `AppDelegate.swift` and putting it directly in my root custom `UINavgiationController.swift` file:

```
    let image = UIImage(named:"HeaderBanner-new")
    self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.defaultPrompt)
```

Still doesn't work. 
Any ideas what's going on - or ideas for a workaround/hack?

Comment: My code is older so not in Swift, but my ObjC actually is the same but uses a resizable image and it does set the image, but does not resize it vertically (it does horizontally).

Comment: UIImage *bgi = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar"];
    UIImage *bgir = [bgi resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:bgir forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Answer (score 1):

It seems NavigationBar.setBackgroundImage doesn't work as expected in iOS 11.

I had the same issue and fixed it by using NavigationBar.barTintColor and it worked.

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46446178/8472539).