# How to add vertical Gradient color in UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, swift4, cagradientlayer

I want to add gradient color in `UINavigationBar`. code for horizontal gradient working perfectly but for vertical gradient, its not showing proper color.

Thanx in advance!!!

**My Current Code for vertical gradient :**

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    /// Applies a background gradient with the given colors
    func applyNavigationGradient( colors : [UIColor]) {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }

        // *** for horizontal gradient ***
        // gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        // gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

        // *** for vertical gradient ***
        // gradientLayer.locations = [0,1]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

         setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working code for swift 4.1. Just put the following in view did load:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    var updatedFrame = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    updatedFrame.size.height += 20
    gradientLayer.frame = updatedFrame
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0) // vertical gradient start
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0) // vertical gradient end

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
    gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
}
```

Comment: Welcome, if this is what you were looking for just thumbs up and make it an approved answer :)

Comment: Should be noted that this won't work with an iOS11 large title option, for gradients on that, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196848/custom-background-image-with-large-titles-navigationbar-in-ios-11